# How to get object properties on element click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, events, scope

I am building a weather app for practice. I get to that point that I have to make an autocomplete input field with data from JSON object. When someone makes an input, it displays the matched data, but on click I want to get two properties from the object. I need to get the longitude and latitude properties from JSON object to make an API request to return the object with the weather data. The content displays properly but I can't make that onClick event listener work. I tried very different things and failed, either was a scope problem or something else. It is one of my first projects and I am in a downfall right now. Please help me. :)

P.S. You can find it on this link: https://objective-edison-1d6da6.netlify.com/

```
// Testing
const search = document.querySelector('#search');
const matchList = document.querySelector('#match-list');
let states;

// Get states
const getStates = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('../data/bg.json');
  states = await res.json();
};

// Filter states
const searchStates = searchText => {
  // Get matches to current text input
  let matches = states.filter(state => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');

    return state.city.match(regex);
  });

  // Clear when input or matches are empty
  if (searchText.length === 0) {
    matches = [];
    matchList.innerHTML = '';
  }

  outputHtml(matches);
};

// Show results in HTML
const outputHtml = matches => {
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    const html = matches
      .map(
        match => `<div class="card match card-body mb-1">
    <h4>${match.city} 
    <span class="text-primary">${match.country}</span></h4>
    <small>Lat: ${match.lat} / Long: ${match.lng}</small>
   </div>`
      )
      .join('');
    matchList.innerHTML = html;
    document.querySelector('.match').addEventListener('click', function() {});
    //Wconsole.log(matches);
    //let test = document.querySelectorAll('#match-list .card');
    //const values = matches.values(city);
  }
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getStates);
search.addEventListener('input', () => searchStates(search.value));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to access the `lat` and `lng` values of the clicked match, if that is the case, here is one way of doing it:

```
const outputHtml = matches => {
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    const html = matches
      .map(
        match => `<div class="card match card-body mb-1" data-lat="`${match.lat}" data-lng="`${match.lng}">
    <h4>${match.city} 
    <span class="text-primary">${match.country}</span></h4>
    <small>Lat: ${match.lat} / Long: ${match.lng}</small>
   </div>`
      )
      .join('');
    matchList.innerHTML = html;
    document.querySelectorAll('.match').forEach(matchElm => {
      matchElm.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
         const { currentTarget } = event;
         const { lat, lng } = currentTarget.dataset;
      });
    });
  }
};
```

I've used the `data-lat` and `data-lng` attributes to store the required values in the element's `dataset` and I've used `document.querySelectorAll('.match')` to get all the elements that have the class `match` not just the first one.

Comment: Genius, thank you. There is only one small problem, when you click on element inside what we selected it returns Undefined. For example, if I click on h4 block, it returns undefined, but if I click on the main block it returns the lat from dataset. I think I can find a solution for it. Thank you for enlightening me about datasets :)

Comment: @GeorgeMilev That is because `event.target` is the clicked element. I've edited my answer to address that.